# Copy SQL Server Maintenance Plan between instances on same server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, maintenance-plans

I have multiple SQL Server 2019 instances on the same server. I've created and exported the first instance's maintenance plan, edited its exported DTSX file to change the instance and plan names to avoid name conflicts, and imported the edited DTSX via SSIS (and DTUTIL) on the same server.

Problem: I see the the both the original and imported plan in SSIS under Stored Packages > MSDB > Maintenance Plans, but NOT under the second instance's Management > Maintenance Plans list in SSMS.

Comment: I believe only Windows server can have only one copy of SSIS installed. So even if you have seven instances of SQL on the same box, you'll only have SSIS devoted to one of them. SSIS will work for all them but will initially only be aware of one of them. I think the following link still holds the answer by modifying MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml to make SQL Server SSIS aware:  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2061/how-to-manage-ssis-packages-stored-in-multiple-sql-server-database-instances/

Comment: Thanks @Sting. That looks very promising. I'll give it a try and report back ASAP.

Comment: That didn't take long at all! Worked perfectly. It's annoying that the SQLSrv installer doesn't update this file with new instances.

Comment: If you'd answer, I'll happily accept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

I believe only Windows server can have only one copy of SSIS installed. So even if you have seven instances of SQL on the same box, you'll only have SSIS devoted to one of them. SSIS will work for all them but will initially only be aware of one of them. I think the following link still holds the answer by modifying MsDtsSrvr.ini.xml to make SQL Server SSIS aware: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2061/how-to-manage-ssis-packages-stored-in-multiple-sql-server-database-instances/